# MacBook Pro 2013 MacOS Big Sur 11.6.3 doesn't show up Wi-Fi login portal

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

I bought a second-hand MacBook Pro 2013 today. I'm trying to connect to my dormitory's Wi-Fi network. Normally when I try to connect to the Wi-Fi network it automatically pops up a new login page where I can input my ID and password to connect to internet.

But this doesn't work on my MacBook. I have been trying to troubleshoot it for almost 3 hours but couldn't find any useful resource.

As far as I've learned from the internet, Apple opens a URL (captive.apple.com) on default browser on the MacBook to show up the login portal of connected Wi-Fi networks. This doesn't work for me.

Some people have solved the issue by opening the file located at `System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app` but that file doesn't exist for me.

I have tried to connect or ping the default gateway of the Wi-Fi network but all tries end up with time out result. I've tried different browsers. I also tried to login the portal page using it's address which is `wifi.gsb.gov.tr` but this didn't work out as well.

Thanks for any suggestion or help.

Comment: For clarification, are you saying you can't even see the wifi network or you can see it but don't get the login page?

Comment: Captive portal fun is cross-platform.  Open a web browser and try to visit nossl.com.

Comment: @fsb I only can't reach/show the login page. I can connect to the Wi-Fi network. But since I can't login, I can't reach the internet.

Comment: @MarcWilson I have also tried it and some other pages didn't work out.

Comment: Are you using any adblockers or extensions?  Do you have 'Pop-up Windows' set to anything other than 'Allow' for that site?

Comment: @fsb I solved the problem somehow, I mean It started working by itself after some time (3 hours). Still thanks for the helps

Comment: Glad you got it to work, however you did it!  Please be sure to add an answer to your question so that others can see what you tried.